# Carbon PHP Get Timestamp from Open/Close Hours

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I store hours in my database as follows

```
8 pm to 2 am
```

or

```
8pm - 2am
8 pm - 2 am
```

When I try to format these with Carbon I get an error about there not being any minutes, all I need to do is compare the Carbon::now() to the referenced open/close times

This is my code

```
$barDays = barDays::where('bar_id', $Bar->id)->where('day_id', $day)->first();
if($barDays === NULL) {
    $barDays = barDays::create([
        'bar_id' => $Bar->id,
        'day_id' => $day,
        'hours' => $Bar->hours,
        'musicType' => $Bar->musicType,
        'type' => $Bar->type
    ]);
    $barDays->save();
} else {
    $barDays = $barDays->hours;
}
$hours = explode(' - ', $barDays, 2);
if(count($hours) < 2) {
    $hours = explode(' to ', $barDays, 2);
} elseif(count($hours) < 2) {
    $hours = explode(' – ', $barDays, 2);
}
if($hours === ['Closed']) {
    $Bar->numPeople = 0;
    $Bar->hours = 'Closed';
    $Bar->save();
} else {
    try {
        $openHours = $hours[0];
        $closedHours = $hours[1];
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return $hours;
    }
    $open = Carbon::createFromTime($openHours, $Bar->timezone);
    $closed = Carbon::parse($closedHours, $Bar->timezone)->addDays(1);
```

The exact error I get is A two digit minute could not be found Data missing

But how do I rectify that?

Comment: in the [docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) show this: `Carbon::createFromTime($hour, $minute, $second, $tz);`

Comment: Right, didn't mean to include that, it doesn't allow for AM/PM specifically, which would be an issue

Answer (score 0):

For one, I don't recommend storing the raw data as `2 pm` or such. An actual datetime will help you in the long run.

If you must though, concat a `:00` after your number and use that when parsing with Carbon.

Comment: But how do I better store it? They're not timestamps, as they change everyday with a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

The method `Carbon::createFromTime` expect the arg `$hour` in 24 hours format, try with this simple snippet

```
$stringHours = '8 pm to 2 am';

$hours = array_map(function($hour) {
        $open = substr($hour, -2) === 'pm'
            ? intval($hour) + 12
            : intval($hour);

        return $open < 24 ? $open : 0;
    }, explode(' to ', $stringHours)
);

Carbon::createFromTime($hours[0], 0, 0, $tz);

//more code...
```